# \ref for data file sources

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am writing my bachelor's in statistics and use a lot of freely downloadable data for my analysis, eg from http://www.fueleconomy.gov/.

The question is, how do I list and `\ref` the files TeX way? I am using BibTeX for literature, but I can't find something for data sources.

I'd like something like:

```
Analyzing \ref{data:car_fuel}, we can clearly see...
```

Resulting into

```
Analyzing Car Consumption for 2012, we can clearly see...
```

and somewhere at the end a list like:

```
Car Consumption for 2012
some comment
source: http://www.fueleconomy.gov/
link: http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/epadata/12data.zip
```

or similar.

Comment: use \cite and make .bib file for your data sources, if you want to keep them separate there are packages for multiple bibliographies

Answer (score 3):

Use `\cite` and make `.bib` file for your data sources, Then use bibtex or biblatex/biber as you would for citations to the literature.

If you want to keep them separate there are packages for multiple bibliographies